# Korrekte Genitivform bei Vereinsnamen, die einen Ort enthalten

Tags: genitive, proper-noun

In meiner Familie ist diese Frage letztens anhand einer Pressemitteilung aufgetaucht. Um jedoch die Anonymität aller Beteiligten zu wahren, und niemanden an den Pranger zu stellen, habe ich als Gegenstand dieser Frage einen (hoffentlich) erfundenen Verein gewählt.

---

Der Golfclub Hintertupflfing will eine Pressemitteilung herausgeben. Darin taucht der Name des Clubs in den vier verschiedenen Fällen auf, exemplarisch anhand der folgenden Sätze:

> Beim [Clubname] sind aus der Bevölkerung mehrere Briefe mit Fragen zum geplanten Ausbau des Vereinsheims eingegangen.
>
> Der [Clubname] möchte natürlich die Bevölkerung einbeziehen.
>
> Weitere Fragen können gerne an den [Clubname] gestellt werden.
>
> Der Vorstand des [Clubname] bemüht sich, etwaige Bedenken möglichst schnell und umfassend auszuräumen.

Die ersten drei Beispielsätze sind relativ eindeutig: Seit das Dativ-*e* im Deutschen nahezu ausgestorben ist, muss es in allen drei Fällen *Golfclub Hintertupflfing* heißen. Was aber ist beim Genitiv der Fall?

Eindeutig ist es, wenn es um *Hintertupflfing**s** Golfclub* geht, oder wenn es *der Vorstand des Golfclub**s*** heißt. Dabei steht jeweils ein Wort im Genitiv.

Wie sieht es aus, wenn der Gesamtausdruck *Golfclub Hintertupflfing* in den Genitiv gesetzt werden muss, wie im vierten Beispielsatz? Denkbar wären:

1. Der Golfclub erhält ein Genitiv-*s*, der Ortsname bleibt ungebeugt, wie es zum Beispiel bei den Werken *Hildegard**s** von Bingen* der Fall wäre:

   > Golfclub**s** Hintertupflfing.
2. *Golfclub Hintertupflfing* (e.V.) wird als voller Name gesehen. Analog zu *Klaus Hintermayr**s** Amtszeit* erhält nur *Hintertupflfing* ein Genitiv-*s*:

   > Golfclub Hintertupflfing**s**
3. *Beide* Teile des Namens werden gebeugt, wie es zum Beispiel beim Namen des *Rote**n** Kreuz**es*** der Fall ist:

   > Golfclub**s** Hintertupflfing**s**

Welche dieser drei Varianten ist korrekt? Bitte nach Möglichkeit mit Belegen antworten.

Comment: Wegen der quasireligiösen Ehrfurcht der Leute vor Markennamen erwarte ich lebhafte Diskussionen. :)

Comment: Was die Tags angeht: warum nicht proper-noun statt place-/brand-names?

Comment: @Matthias Kommt davon, wenn man nur auf Deutsch denkt und sucht … aber [tag:eigenname] ist noch gar nicht mit [tag:proper-noun] synonymisiert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Korrekt ist Variante 1

> des Golfclubs Hintertupflfing

Als klarste Referenz dafür habe ich eine Seite bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Apposition-35326) gefunden. Sie ordnet diese Art von Namen als enge Apposition ein, bei der die Apposition hinter dem Bezugswort steht, und schreibt:

> Die Apposition wird nicht flektiert:
>   im Zentrum der Stadt Frankfurt
>   die Regierung des Kantons Aargau

Variante 2 ist schlicht falsch. Variante 3 funktioniert auch, wenn es in Hintertupflfing nur einen Golfclub gibt, behandelt *Hintertupflfing* aber nicht als Teil des Namens, sondern als Genitivattribut, im Sinne von

> Der Golfclub Hintertupflfings heißt "Golfsportverein Hintertupflfing".

Answer (score 0):

Die erste Variante impliziert, dass es nur einen ganz bestimmten Golfclub in Hintertupfing gäbe. Ja, Normalfall. Nimm einen Fußballclub und einen größeren Ort, dann ist es eindeutig:

> Die Tabellenlage des Fußballclubs Hamburg ist düster.

Die zweite Variante funktioniert nur mit Eigennamen. Der Leser weiß dann auch, dass er nach diesem Eigennamen suchen muss.

> Die Tabellenlage Fußballclub Hamburgs ist düster.

Die dritte Variante ist das Gegenteil der ersten, sie impliziert, dass es sich nur um einen der vielen Fußballclubs Hamburgs handelte.

> Die Tabellenlage dieses Fußballclubs Hamburgs ist düster.

Comment: Den ersten und dritten Satz bzw. die Erläuterung dazu verstehe ich, aber den zweiten nicht. Was ist denn da der Eigenname? Hamburg? Falls der Eigenname aber "Fußballclub Hamburg" ist, würde ich doch eher für _"Die Tabellenlage des Fußballclub Hamburg ist düster"_. Ohne Genitiv-s. Ich kann aber nichts belegen, es ist nur mein Sprachgefühl.

Comment: Hab das *des* rausgeworfen, dann passt es.

Comment: Es heißt "Die Lage des HSVs ist düster.", keinesfalls "Die Lage HSVs ist düster", wie es auch "Die Lage des Onkels ist düster."  Zwar heißt es auch "DIe Lage König Ottos ist heikel" oder "Die Lage Klaus Lages ist prächtig". Begründen kann ich es aber nicht. Liegt es an Person vs. Organisation? "Die Lage des Vereins ist gut." vs. "Die Lage Holgers ist übel."

Comment: Nimm statt HSV einfach St.Pauli. *Die Tabellenlage St. Paulis ist düster*.

Comment: Nimm statt St. Pauli einfach [*Fußballclub St. Pauli*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_St._Pauli). Und dann?